# getIdToken() is not a function, even if It is used like a function in firebase document

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am dealing with firebase auth now and I was following this Firebase document.

Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#sign_in

```
// When the user signs in with email and password.
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword('user@example.com', 'password').then(user => {
  // Get the user's ID token as it is needed to exchange for a session cookie.
  return user.getIdToken().then(idToken = > {
    // Session login endpoint is queried and the session cookie is set.
    // CSRF protection should be taken into account.
    // ...
    const csrfToken = getCookie('csrfToken')
    return postIdTokenToSessionLogin('/sessionLogin', idToken, csrfToken);
  });
})
```

I expected that I could get a token by using that function. But It doesn't work because user in the code doesn't have getIdToken() function.

Comment: Maybe it is because of space in arrow function = >

Comment: what's the firebase/auth package version you are using?

Comment: @Federkun It is 7.22

Comment: @LazarNikolic I fixed that part, but I got same error still..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the id token, just call auth's `currentUser#getIdToken` directly.

```
const idToken = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
```

Comment: This only works occasionally for me. I have this exact line of code inside an async function, and sometimes there's a idToken and sometimes it's undefined. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Apparently I have to wrap this ins `onAuthStateChanged` to get the current user. now I have a token object with a bunch of single letter properties... letter `i` contains my token. I must be missing something here

Answer (score 11):

Seems like things changed since **7.*** version. To get it:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword('user@example.com', 'password').then(({ user }) => {
  // Get the user's ID token as it is needed to exchange for a session cookie.
  return user.getIdToken().then(idToken = > {
    // Session login endpoint is queried and the session cookie is set.
    // CSRF protection should be taken into account.
    // ...
    const csrfToken = getCookie('csrfToken')
    return postIdTokenToSessionLogin('/sessionLogin', idToken, csrfToken);
  });
})
```

Note, that you need to use `user.user.getIdToken()` now, or just use destructuring  as I did in the example.

Comment: destructuring params of user as **.then(({ user })** did the job. as from firebase 7.0.0 the response of signInWithEmailAndPassword to get token becomes **user.user.getIdToken()** instead of user.getIdToken()